# Django: Permalinks for Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, reverse, permalinks

I know the link template to reach an object is like following:

```
"{{ domain }}/{{ admin_dir }}/{{ appname }}/{{ modelname }}/{{ pk }}"
```

Is there a way built-in to get a permalink for an object?

```
from django.contrib import admin

def get_admin_permalink(instance, admin_site=admin.site):
    # returns admin URL for instance change page
    raise NotImplemented
```

#### EDIT

It seems in v1.1 [`admin` has named URLs](http://www.codekoala.com/blog/2009/feb/24/pluggable-django-apps-and-djangos-admin/). Unfortunately it's not yet released.

Comment: Yep, waiting for 1.1 is the only solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.1 is out, the doc is right here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

I also used it a bit, the admin namespace will have to be specified whenever you are fetching an existing admin url.

```
# in urls.py, assuming you have a customized view
url(r'foo/$', 'foo', name='foo_index'),

# in the template, to get the admin url
{% url admin:foo_index %}
```

In 1.1, whenever an admin url is fetched, you'll have to specify the 'admin' namespace.